# How to avoid or stop multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the flotchart plugin, and I was trying to know when and where the user hovers on the chart and get more information from database regarding that chart value.

For example, if the user hovers on a date like "24 May" then an ajax call will be made and all the data for "24 May" will be appended to a div.

Here is my code

```
$("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
            position: "absolute",
            display: "none",
            border: "1px solid #fdd",
            padding: "2px",
            "background-color": "#fee",
            opacity: 0.80
}).appendTo("body");

$("#visitor-chart").on("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
  if (item) {
    var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
      y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
      if (typeof x !== 'undefined') {
        $.get("/ajax/graph?param="+item.datapoint[0]).done(function(result){ 
          $("#graf").html(result); 
        })  
      }
      $("#tooltip").html(item.series.label + " of " + x + " = " + y)
        .css({
          top: item.pageY + 5,
          left: item.pageX + 5
        })
        .fadeIn(200);
  } else {
    $("#tooltip").hide();
  }
});
```

Now the problem is whenever I hover on any date, it sends multiple ajax requests like 10-15 requests immediately. How can I avoid extra ajax requests?

Comment: The letter "I", when referencing yourself, should always be capitalized. I've fixed it here, but please be aware of this in future questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding a flag to the top of the function which checks to see if the ajax call has been fired. Here is some sudo code, obviously you will need to make this work with your example.

```
var isAjaxing = false
$().on("click", function(){
    if(isAjaxing) return;
    isAjaxing = true;

    $.ajax(url, function(){
       isAjaxing = false;
    })
})
```

This will lock out the function until the ajax call is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) jQuery plugin and throttle your request. It also contains the code samples.

You can do something like this

```
$("#visitor-chart").on("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
...
    $.throttle(makeYourAjaxCallHere, 300)
...
});
```

Comment: You explained the what, but could you explain why your answer is better then the former?

Comment: It is nothing wrong with the solution from Tom, but this plugin was developed especially for cases like yours and you have multiple options to set when you are using it, you can fire the first call after a certain time has passed and you have full control over the time between calls.