# AJAX sending multiple requests after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just want one click to equal one submit in my jQuery code.

I've read quite a few posts on this same topic but I think mine is different. I do have a `mouseleave` and `focusout` event that I'm using to find errors in user input. Those functions feed down into the function that is submitting multiple times. The more times I hit `mouseleave` and `focusout` the more times my Ajax request is submitted. But I need `mouseleave` and `focusout` to continue to work and check the users input, that's why I'm not using `one`. Please see my code below, the function that I think is submitting multiple times is `handleButtonClicksAfterError`

```
function getCreditAmountToSend(modal){
  console.log("getCreditAmountToSend");
  var checkBox = $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-checkbox");
  checkBox.change(function(){
    if($(checkBox).is(":checked")) {
      var creditAmount = +(sessionStorage.getItem("creditAmount"));
      sessionStorage.setItem('amountToSend', creditAmount);
    }
  });
  var pendingCreditAmount = $(modal).contents().find("#pending_credit_amount");
  pendingCreditAmount.on({
    mouseleave: function(){
      if(pendingCreditAmount.val() != ""){
        adminForGetPendingCredit(modal); 
      }
    },
    focusout: function(){
      if(pendingCreditAmount.val() != ""){      
        adminForGetPendingCredit(modal);
      }  
    }
  });
}

function adminForGetPendingCredit(modal){
  console.log("adminForGetPendingCredit");
  var checkBox = $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-checkbox");
  if(!$(checkBox).is(":checked")) {
    var enteredAmount = +($(modal).contents().find("#pending_credit_amount").val());
    var creditAmount = +(sessionStorage.getItem("creditAmount"));
    sessionStorage.setItem('enteredAmount', enteredAmount);
    doWeDisplayError(modal,creditAmount, enteredAmount); 
  }
}

function doWeDisplayError(modal,creditAmount, enteredAmount){
  console.log("doWeDisplayError");
  $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-continue-shopping").prop("disabled", false);
  $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-checkout").prop("disabled", false);  
  if(creditAmount < enteredAmount){
    $(modal).contents().find("#pending_credit_amount").val("");
    $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-continue-shopping").prop("disabled", true);
    $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-checkout").prop("disabled", true);
    displayError();
  }
  else{
    handleButtonClicksAfterError(modal, enteredAmount);
  }
}

function handleButtonClicksAfterError(modal, enteredAmount){
  // this is the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  console.log("handleButtonClicksAfterError");
  sessionStorage.setItem('amountToSend', enteredAmount);
  var continueButton = $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-continue-shopping");
  continueButton.click(function() {
      modal.hide();
  });
  var checkoutButton = $(modal).contents().find("#fresh-credit-checkout");
  checkoutButton.click(function() {
      console.log("handleButtonClicksAfterError");
      sendData();
  });
}

function displayError(){
    console.log("displayError");
  $(function(){
    $("#fresh-credit-iframe").contents().find("#pending_credit_amount").attr("placeholder", "Whoops, that was too much");
    $("#fresh-credit-iframe").contents().find("#pending_credit_amount").attr({
      class: "form-control form-control-red"
    });
    sessionStorage.removeItem('enteredAmount');
  });
}
```

This is the function that actually `POST`s the data

```
function sendData(){
  var amountToSend = sessionStorage.getItem("amountToSend");
  var products = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem("products"));
  console.log("sendData");
  console.log("This is the amount to send " + amountToSend);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/apps/proxy/return_draft_order",
      data: {amountToSend, products},
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      complete: function(data) {
        window.location.href = data.responseText;
        console.log("This is the URL from poll " + data.responseText );
        return false;
      },
    });
}
```

Comment: You need the flag that the ajax has fired with a var, then check that var before sending anymore requests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418316/how-to-avoid-or-stop-multiple-ajax-request/37418473#37418473

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended up being super simple.. I just needed the jQuery `off` method.. I attached it to the button before click and everything is peachy.. Looks like this:

```
checkoutButton.off().click(function(){});
```

`off` clears all the previous event handlers and then just proceeds with `Click`

Pretty cool, to read more check it out [here](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: i mean... or you can stop re-binding the event over and over. that'd certainly work. Not much reason to bind a click event within a function that gets called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

use ***async:false*** to prevent multiple request

```
 $(document).off('click').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: ,
            async:false,
            cache: false,
            data:{}
             ,
            success: function(data){

            },
            error:function(data){
            }
        });   

    });
```